# HTML5 Game is working in appmobi launcher pad but not as apk build

Tags: android, appmobi

Hi I have created the pure html5/css3/js based Game and i tested with appmobi (app labs launcher) for android. Touch events were working fine on launcher but when i created the build with the same source via app.mobi xdk (Touch events are not working).

Answer (score 0):

use phonegap if your game size is less than 9.MB.